# How can I have the second content area display varying information as per the links in the first column?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I would like column 2 to display a description of each button from column 1.

The user is to be able to click on any of the buttons from column 1 and column 2 is to populate with content.

I have spent very long working with iFrames and collapsibles but cannot get it to work and my knowledge is very limited.

Do you know of a way to solve this?

```
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; 
}

.column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="column1" style="background-color:#aaa;">
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                                <button class="collapsible" 
data-parent="#myGroup">################</button>
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="column2" style="background-color:#bbb;">
                                                <p>Some text..</p>
                                        </div>
                                        </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear - but I'll do what I can to assist based on what I think you're asking.

It sounds like you'd like `.column2` to dynamically display data based on the button pressed in `.column1`. The first thing I'd recommend is to have a unique identifier on each button (an ID for example). This is going to allow you to identify which information needs to be put into `.column2`. Otherwise, you can check this anonymously, but that could lead you to some confusion later.

Next, you'll need to write some jQuery/JavaScript in order to listen for the button click, and then do something. For example (doing it anonymously):

```
$('.collapsible').click(function(){
   //do something, and eventually...
   $('.column2').html(/*the data*/);
});
```

Now, the next portion really depends on *where* you're getting your data from. One way you can do this is through a `$.post()` request through jQuery [(Link to Documentation on $.post())](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to an external source that feeds you the information (such as a PHP file). Otherwise, you could always add the data directly to the DOM (although this could get messy, along with a slough of other issues that could come from it like formatting, page speeds, etc).

If you *did* choose to put it into the DOM, it might look something like:

```
<button class="collapsible" data-parent="#myGroup" data-description="Some text pertaining to the button that the user clicked">#########</button>
```

And in this case, you would access this with:

```
$('.collapsible').click(function(){
    var description = $(this).attr('data-description');
    $('.column2').html(description);
});
```

Obviously you would probably want to format the data, rather than just spitting text into a `div`, so you could either style it based on the `div`, or add a paragraph/span/another DOM element around it, like:

```
 $('.collapsible').click(function(){
    var description = '<p class="description-class">' + $(this).attr('data-description') + '</p>';
    $('.column2').html(description);
});
```